# How do I check values of input parameter of multiple values in HANA scripted calculation views

Tags: hana

We need to use a script based calculation views with multiple parameters. We have a problem with passing 'all values'. Having seen many posts on this, we decided to default the input parameters to '%'. Now we need to check the input parameter values in the script.

I tried using if an statement in my calc view script

`if :P_MATNR = '%' then
       vfilmatnr := ' "MATNR" LIKE ( '||:P_MATNR||' )';
else
   vfilmatnr := ' "MATNR" IN ( '||:P_MATNR||' )';
end if;`

This doesn't seem to work. Can someone please assist? I tried searching all blogs and googling my head off... but can't find an appropriate answer.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

If P_MATNR has a value of '%' which maps to all values, you don't require a filtering in that case

So, you can modify the script as follows

```
if :P_MATNR <> '%' then
   vfilmatnr := ' "MATNR" IN ( '||:P_MATNR||' )';
end if;
```

Actually, following criteria always returns "true" so why adda code line for nothing?

```
   vfilmatnr := ' "MATNR" LIKE ( '%' )';
```

Comment: it does not seem to work when checking against '%'. it works if i use below syntax <br/> `if not(:P_MATNR LIKE '%All%' then`